# How to create programmatically a spring PublishSubscribeChannel

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to create programmatically the following XML config

```
<int:channel id="sample">
</int:channel>
```

What i can do is the following

```
PublishSubscribeChannel channel = new PublishSubscribeChannel();
```

But there is no method to assign the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `<int:channel>` produces `DirectChannel` bean.

And if you want to do it programatically and have entire Messaging Infrastructure you should configure it as bean anyway:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public MessageChannel sample() {
       return new DirectChannel();
   }

}
```

The `id` attribute is a key feature of Spring IOC container and, of course, it isn't responcibility of concrete class.

Seems to me you should to take a look into the new stuff of [Spring Integration 4.0](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/31/spring-integration-3-0-2-and-4-0-milestone-4-released).

Answer (score 0):

The "id" is specific to a Spring application context and helps identify each instance that is being defined inside the application context.

What you have in there translates, more "verbosely" to this Spring config:

```
<bean id="sample" class="org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel" />
```

The "id" identifies, like a name, a class DirectChannel instance within the context of a Spring ApplicationContext. The default channel used for a "int:channel" definition is the DirectChannel class, not PublishSubscribeChannel ([DirectChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration)).

But, apart from the channel itself, Spring Integration creates some other beans behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of wiring/injecting `DirectChannel` Bean: For Spring `3.2.3.RELEASE` version

Code in Controller/Config Loader file:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigControllerLoader {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("direct-channel-bean")
  DirectChannel drtChannel;
}
```

Context file bean definition:

```
<int:channel id="direct-channel-bean"></int:channel>
```